# Problema al generar archivos dentro de un ZIP

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc

He generado este método con los parámetros traídos de mi clase de gestión de base de datos, el problema esta en que puedo generar mi archivo ZIP sin ningún problema pero no tengo ningún archivo html.

```
 public static string Execute(Models.ReportTibaTimeModel _report, string PathTemplate, string PathFile, string Pass)
    {
        string sFile = string.Empty;

        ReportesBL _rpt = new ReportesBL();
        DataSet ds = _rpt.ReportTibaTime( _report.ProgramName == null? "_": _report.ProgramName, _report.EpiFeatureName == null? "_": _report.EpiFeatureName, _report.HouseNumber == null? "_":_report.HouseNumber);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MaestrosBL _maestros = new MaestrosBL();

            sFile = string.Format("{0}_{1}.zip", _report.usuario.Trim(), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

            string PathFolder = PathFile + sFile.Substring(0, sFile.Length - 6);
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(PathFolder))
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(PathFolder);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(PathFolder);


            foreach (DataRow drAdv in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                //aqui empezamos a zamparle a aquel (HTM) todaaaaa la data 
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add("SEGMENTS");
                dt.Columns.Add("HOUSE_NUMBER");
                dt.Columns.Add("NATURAL_START_TIME");
                dt.Columns.Add("NATURAL_END_TIME");
                dt.Columns.Add("SLOT_DURATION");
                dt.Columns.Add("SEGMENT_NAME");
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g" });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m" });


                string tab = "\t";

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.AppendLine("<html>");
                sb.AppendLine(tab + "<body>");
                sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table>");

                // aqui termino de hacer el header
                sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dc.ColumnName);
                }

                sb.AppendLine("</tr>");

                // parte de mi data rows
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
                        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
                    }

                    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                }

                sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "</table>");
                sb.AppendLine(tab + "</body>");
                sb.AppendLine("</html>");

                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(PathFolder + "\\" + "cuquitas.htm");

                file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                file.Close();

            }

            Helper.ZipFolder(PathFolder, PathFile, sFile);
         }
       return sFile;

 }
```

Comment: y en que momento agregas el archivo HTML al zip? por lo que veo solo creas el zip.

Comment: He probado tu codigo y genera el html perfectamente. Creo que el problema es el bucle en el que lo haces, que no tiene sentido. Quita el `foreach (DataRow drAdv in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {` y prueba

Comment: Revisa este enlace: [mcve].

Comment: gracias @Pikoh la situacion esta en que debo generar N numeros de archivos pero no se como hacer la conbinacion para que dentro de mi ZIP me agregue los archivos que necesito. Vos sabrias como hacerlo?